# Android HashMap con custom adapter

Tags: java, android, json, hashmap

El propósito del código es imprimir los nombres de las capítulos cuando la temporada está en la misma posicion, aquí un ejemplo,

```
tengo una serie "x" con 2 temporadas
Temporada 1 [10 capitulos] Temporada 2 [10 capitulos}]
serie "e" con 1 temporada
Temporada 1 [8 capitulos]
Y se tiene que mostrar de la siguiente manera en un listview
Serie x
Temporada 1 
        -----> Capitulo 1
        ----->Capitulo 2
        -----> etc
Temporada 2 
        -----> Capitulo 1
        ----->Capitulo 2
        -----> etc
```

Y esto lo realizo correctamente, el problema es en temporada 1, se muestra tambien los capitulos de la temporada 1 de la serie "e", alguien sabe a que se debe?

Mis codigos
CON ESTE LLENO UN HASHMPAP CON UN CUSTOM ADAPTER DE ARRAYLIST

```
for (int j = 0; j < resultadosURL.length(); j++) {
                    JSONObject json_dataURL = resultadosURL.getJSONObject(j);
                    nombres_capitulos.add(json_dataURL.getString("nombre"));
                    url.add(json_dataURL.getString("url"));
                    temporada.add(json_dataURL.getInt("temporada"));
                }
                nombresCapitulos.put(json_data.getString("titulo"), new SerieTemp(nombres_capitulos, temporada, url));
            }
```

CON ESTE ACCEDO MEDIANTE KEY

```
nombresCapitulos.get(url_img.keySet().toArray()[position].toString())
```

Y AQUI MUESTO LOS RESULTADOS DE ESE KEY

```
for (int i = 1; i <= UtilActividad.getSerie().getTEMPORADAS(); i++){
            child = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int j = 0; j < UtilActividad.getSerie().getNombresCapitulos().getNombres_capitulos().size(); j++){
                if(UtilActividad.getSerie().getNombresCapitulos().getTemporada().get(j) == i){
                    child.add(UtilActividad.getSerie().getNombresCapitulos().getNombres_capitulos().get(j));
                }
            }
            childItems.add(child);
```

Pero me imprimen los resultados de todo sin importar las keys

Comment: "Y AQUI MUESTO LOS RESULTADOS DE ESE KEY". como los muestras?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Por favor evita los textos en mayúsculas en tus preguntas (y respuestas).

Comment: Disculpen mis errores, en verdad trataré de mejorar en mis próximas duda, pero ya lo logré hacer funcionar, muchas gracias.